# Can we find a solution for this indefinite sum using finite calculus?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus

I was recently introduced to Finite Calculus through Graham and Knuth. I stumbled upon this sum earlier today in a problem posted in this site, although I cannot link to it right now because I'm on the mobile app. I just wanted to know if it is possible to analyze it through calculus

The sum is $$ \sum_0^M \frac {(n^2)_x}{(n)^{x+1}} dx$$

Where I use $(n)_x$ for the falling factorial power and $(n)^x$ for the rising factorial

I know this is way out of my league (because I just started reading on the subject), I just want to know if it's possible to find a solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $k_x$ mean?

Comment: I'm using that notation for falling factorial power since I can't find the proper LaTex syntaxis